# Apache 403 error except from localhost

Tags: apache, wamp

When i try to connect to my WAMP server using anything but localhost i get error 403.

```
[Tue Sep 24 10:23:06.363000 2013] [access_compat:error] [pid 2912:tid 1520] [client ip:ip:ip:ip:49886] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/
[Tue Sep 24 10:23:06.916000 2013] [access_compat:error] [pid 2912:tid 1520] [client ip:ip:ip:ip:49886] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
```

I tried to start the wamp services as my account (running on win7 x64). I tried to edit these lines in the httpd.config

```
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

but i still get the error.
EDIT: I installed an older version of WAMP (2.2E) and everything works fine not sure what's different in the newest version (2.4)

Answer (score 1):

Change that section back to

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

That section controls access to your root drive and that should always be `Deny from all'

Look for this section of https.conf

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
```

And change the section below that to

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1 localhost
```

Also make sure that your hosts file `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\host` has these entries

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1        localhost
```

EDIT:

You didn't actually say you were using WAMP 2.4. It would have helped:

In that case, [read this thread](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,119754), from the wampserver forum, it describes how to fix a bunch of 2.4 issues.

Comment: I did all these things and nothing changed i still can't access it from anywhere except if i type localhost/127.0.0.1

Comment: I've had WAMP installed and running just fine many times before so i think it must be some new security update from WIN7